# Edit this expression to turn fixed bottom in fixed top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, fixed

this function is supoused to work in iphone,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#head').css('position','fixed');
  window.onscroll = function() {
      document.getElementById('head').style.top =
         (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight + 25) + 'px';
        // alert((window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - 25) + 'px');
    };
});
```

but it's supoused to keep the div (25px) at the bottom of the page, i need it on top of the page no matter how much i scroll

i'm tring like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#head').css('position','fixed');
    var height = $('#head').height();
  window.onscroll = function() {
      document.getElementById('head').style.top =
         (window.pageYOffset) - height + 'px';
        // alert(window.pageYOffset); alert(window.innerHeight);
    };
});
```

but it seems that the #head div is not following properly the scroll (it seems like it bounces), any idea what i'm missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position `fixed` do not work in iPhone. So it is bound to bounce whenever you scroll the page until the `scroll` handler set its new position.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#head').css('position','absolute');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      $('#head').css({
         top: window.pageYOffset
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: i mean i don't get the div where i want it (i know i have to wait untill the scroll is finished) test it here if you want http://piscolabis.info/licht

Comment: its weird because the scroll allways looks at the same position but there is a space (about head's size) on top of the div and if I remove  - $('#head').height(); head dissapears onscroll :S check the link if you want

Comment: top: ($(window).height() + window.pageYOffset - $('#head').height()*2 +100); that looks ok, why do i have to add that?

Comment: Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: firefox and iphone 4's safari

Comment: `window.pageYOffset` is only supported in webkit browsers and mostly used of iPad or iPhone. For desktop borwsers we sue `$(window).scrollTop()`.

Comment: It will not work in `Firefox`. You should use `window.pageYOffset` only for `iPad` and for rest all `$(window).scrollTop()`.

Comment: i only need suport for iphone

Comment: I am more worried on the $('#head').height()*2 +100, $('#head').height()*3/2 seems to be more acurate, any idea why i have to add that?

Comment: If you are not testing in `iPhone` then test in chrome and not FF because chrome supports `window.pageYOffset`. You have to set any of those value it works fine.

Comment: We had to use the `outerHeight`. Try my edited answer now its perfect I tested in Chrome.

Comment: It works fine now, make sure you vote and mark this as an answer after you verify it, thanks.

Comment: Yes i am testing in iphone! and i really appreciate your help and time but it does not keep the div at the top of the page :( more likely at the bottom (but there still a gap at the bottom...) http://keepyourlinks.com/uploads/284/la%20foto.PNG

Comment: I need it at the TOP of the page (#head) all the time! xD don't tell me you understood bottom?! sorry if i didn't express myself properly but check out the title of the question

Answer (score 0):

Try a little more jQuery:

`window.onscroll = function() { $('#head').offset(0,0); }`